# Pull Frequency Parameters in MVC architecture

Tags: mvc

Assume a simple [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (Single-page application), *maybe a dashboard* and these basic conditions:

- The **Model** contains methods for accessing and displaying data;
- The **View** contains methods to load templates and apply model.data to  template;
- The **Controller** manages the user commands;
- The **Router** handles the navigation;

In our example, we will make sure that the user can configure the dashboard to update itself every *N* seconds pulling new data from *back-end* (*pullFrequency*).

In which component is proper set up the *pullFrequency* parameter:

1. Model?
2. View?
3. Controller?
4. Router?
5. Somewhere else?

Comment: I would not call this a "global" variable. It will only exist in one location, and really only one object (the one initiating the refresh) would need it anyway.

Comment: @JohnGaughan _Initializer_. good point. In this case, the choice may vary **depending** on whether I choose to put a button to begin the update, or if the update starts because the view fetches the data prior to rendering. is that correct?

Comment: Possibly, but the distinction is slim at the abstract level. Either way, you have a single object responsible for requesting updates at a given frequency. *Something* has to create that object and possibly give it a message to start doing its task, but that is outside the scope of my original point that the frequency is not really global.

Comment: Updated the title to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the pullFrequency parameter is used client-side to set up the polling; if you're happy to restrict yourself to browsers that support HTML5 then the cleanest solution may be to have a sensible default in your page and if the user wants to update it, pop it in Local Storage ( see http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html ). That way your main application can be completely oblivious to the setting - after all it's not relevant to anything server-side.

The downside of this approach is that it needs to be set separately on each device the user uses - but that's not necessarily bad, a user may want rapid refresh on his desktop with super-fast line, but much less on his tablet / phone when out on the move.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is a solution and restrict to HTML5 might not be a problem. _The point is, in that case, the components are not isolated, independent, and basically, they are not reusable modules (per external dependencies)_.